# Unable to integrate firebase with angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:219:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

219     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationInitStatus, [{ optional: true; }]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:220:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

220     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:235:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

235     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:236:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

236     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<ApplicationModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:237:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

237     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:403:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

403     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationRef, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:404:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

404     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:749:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

749     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Compiler, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:750:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

750     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5066:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

5066     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<PlatformRef, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5067:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

5067     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6454:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6454     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SystemJsNgModuleLoader, [null, { optional: true; }]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6455:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

6455     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6651:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6651     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Testability, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6652:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

6652     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6696:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6696     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<TestabilityRegistry, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6697:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

6697     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:9639:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

9639     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ɵConsole, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:9640:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

9640     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<ɵConsole>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:13:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

13     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAuth, [null, { optional: true; }, null, null]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:14:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

14     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.d.ts:4:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

4     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.d.ts:5:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

5     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.d.ts:6:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

6     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:48:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

48     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireModule, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:49:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

49     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireModule, never, never, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:50:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/home/adarsh/myangularprojet/angular-auth/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

50     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✖ Failed to compile.

Comment: Please don't just post the unformatted, giant error message. Please tell us what you want to achieve, what you tried and format your error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the angularfire2 package? If yes, then switch to @angular/fire package because angularfire2 is deprecated. That could be causing issues.

Also, don't install @angular/fire via npm but rather use `ng add @angular/fire`.